# C# use method for multiple classes / types

Tags: c#, sqlite

I like to use a method for different kind of classes/types. I could do something like this:

```cs
public void ClearTable(string type)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath))
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case "Project":
                        connection.DropTable<Project>();
                        connection.CreateTable<Project>();
                        break;

                    case "Task":
                        connection.DropTable<Task>();
                        connection.CreateTable<Task>();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Where, for example "Project" in DropTable is a name of a class. But I prefer more something more generic like (this is the part where I am not sure what to do):

```cs
public void ClearTable(Type t)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath))
            {
                connection.DropTable<t>();
                connection.CreateTable<t>();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

How can I use something like the last method to support multiple kind of classes/types?

Comment: Change your method signature to: `public void ClearTable<T>()`

Comment: @Robert were it generics your are looking for (see my answer) or are your forced to call the method with a type as a parameter and to create the generic method at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for **Generics**

With generics you could write code like this:

```
public void ClearTable<TType>()
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath))
        {
            connection.DropTable<TType>();
            connection.CreateTable<TType>();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You then can call the method and give any type as generic parameter:

```
ClearTable<MyDomainModel>();
```

In additition you could restrict the generic parameter `TType` with a `where` clause.

```
public void ClearTable<TType>()
    where TType : IDomainModel
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Now you can only give types which inherit from `IDomainModel` as generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the code that calls `ClearTable` looks like.

**Compile time binding**

If it knows the type at compile time, you can change your prototype to

```
public void ClearTable<T>()
```

...and call it with

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.ClearTable<Task>();
```

or

```
myClass.ClearTable<Project>();
```

**Run-time binding**

If the type is not known until run-time, and you truly have to pass it as a string like that, you could set up a delegate dictionary like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<SQLLiteConnection>> _actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<SQLLiteConnection>>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        _actions.Add("Project", conn => conn.DropTable<Project>());
        _actions.Add("Task", conn => conn.DropTable<Task>());
    }

    public void ClearTable(string type)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath))
            {
                var action = _actions[type](connection);
                action(connection);
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException ex1)
        { 
            Log.Info(String.Format("{0} is not a supported type.", type));
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex2)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex2.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented Iqon's solution and it works for me. Based on your reputation and "complexity" of your code, better error handling etc. I have a feeling your code will be more stable, save and is more according to the C# conventions. I'm quiet new with C# and like to become a better developer. With the intention of me becoming a better developer, not saying Iqon's solution is bad - it is basically my "bad" code made better, can you confirm that your code is "better" than Iqon's? If you like, can you also please explain why?

Comment: The first half of my solution is identical to Iqon's, so it is not "better," it is equal :) The second half you would only use in the unusual circumstance where the type must be passed as a string and is only determined at run-time.